# Configure API Jersey for http and https

Tags: java, tomcat

is possible to make some API via http and some via https, for example:

```
localhost:8080/MyWebServices/api/getSomething
```

and another API with https, for example:

```
localhost:8443/MyWebServices/api/getB
```

My API example is:

```
@Path("/getSomething")
@GET
@ManagedAsync
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getSomethingA(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response){
....
}
```

and in Tomcat i have the Connector port="8080" and, for example:

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
   maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
   keystoreFile="c:\mkyongkeystore"
   keystorePass="password" />
```

i must configure the web.xml? or where? for have those features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of your connectors are set up correctly, you should be able to hit your API from port 8080 as well as 8443.

If you want to secure distinct parts of your application explicitely, you can use one or more security-constraints in your application's **web.xml**

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/whatever/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

This will prevent any non-ssl requests (matching the url pattern) from accessing the webapp.